# Log on "my app" using home screen passcode or touchid

Tags: iphone, authentication, keychain, touch-id

Is it possible to have the lock screen pin/touchid to also authenticate my application if this is protected the same way using a pin/touchid? So I dont have to do this twice when opening an actionable notification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use home screen Passcode or TouchID to authenticate the app with in **timeInterval** by setting a property **touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration** which is newly introduce in LocalAuthentication Framework in iOS9.

Code snippet(Example):-

```
let laContext = LAContext()
let timeInterval = 10 // In Seconds

LAContext.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration = timeInterval

   ......
   ......
```

If the device was successfully unlocked by TouchID/Passcode within this time interval, then Touch ID authentication on this context will succeed automatically and the reply block will be called without prompting user for Touch ID Authentication.

**Note:-** The **Maximum supported interval is 5 minutes** and setting the value beyond 5 minutes does not increase the accepted interval.